# Coding Standards for pure C (not C++)

Tags: c, coding-style

I come from a java background (from my CS classes) and a semester of C++.  I am just finishing up a OpenCV project for my Co-Op that's in pure C, so I'm a bit late in asking this question.

**What are the design processes and coding standards for pure C?**

I'm familiar with object oriented programming, design and best practices.  I'm just a bit at a loss at a non-object oriented language like C.  Every single variable and function appears to be global.  It makes it feel like a real mess to me.

Comment: Functions are "global", but variables can have different scopes...

Comment: functions can of course be global or file static

Answer (score 9):

I have no professionnal experience on C (only on C++), so don't take my advices, tricks and tips too seriously, as they are "object-like-oriented".

### Almost Object C?

Simulating basic object-like features can be done easily:

In the header, forward declare your type, typedef it, and declare the "methods". For example:

```
/* MyString.h */

#include <string.h>

/* Forward declaration */
struct StructMyString ;

/* Typedef of forward-declaration (note: Not possible in C++) */
typedef struct StructMyString MyString ;

MyString *       MyString_new() ;
MyString *       MyString_create(const char * p_pString) ;
void             MyString_delete(MyString * p_pThis) ;
size_t           MyString_length(const MyString * p_pThis) ;

MyString *       MyString_copy(MyString * p_pThis, const MyString * p_pSource) ;
MyString *       MyString_concat(MyString * p_pThis, const MyString * p_pSource) ;

const char *     MyString_get_c_string(const MyString * p_pThis) ;
MyString *       MyString_copy_c_string(MyString * p_pThis, const char * p_pSource) ;
MyString *       MyString_concat_c_string(MyString * p_pThis, const char * p_pSource) ;
```

You'll see each functions is prefixed. I choose the name of the "struct" to make sure there won't be collision with another code.

You'll see, too, that I used "p_pThis" to keep with the OO-like idea.

In the source file, define your type, and define the functions:

```
/* MyString.c */

#include "MyString.h"

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct StructMyString
{
   char *      m_pString ;
   size_t      m_iSize ;
} ;

MyString * MyString_new()
{
   MyString * pMyString = malloc(sizeof(MyString)) ;

   pMyString->m_iSize = 0 ;
   pMyString->m_pString = malloc((pMyString->m_iSize + 1) * sizeof(char)) ;
   pMyString->m_pString[0] = 0 ;

   return pMyString ;
}

/* etc. */
```

If you want "private" functions (or private global variables), declare them static in the C source. This way, they won't be visible outside:

```
static void doSomethingPrivate()
{
   /* etc. */
}

static int g_iMyPrivateCounter = 0 ;
```

If you want inheritance, then you're almost screwed. If you believed everything in C was global, including variable, then you should get more experience in C before even trying to think how inheritance could be simulated.

### Misc. Tips

#### Avoid multiple code-paths.

For example, multiple returns is risky. For example:

```
void doSomething(int i)
{
   void * p = malloc(25) ;

   if(i > 0)
   {
      /* this will leak memory ! */
      return ;
   }

   free(p) ;
}
```

#### Avoid non-const globals

This include "static" variables (which are not static functions).

Global non-const variables are almost always a bad idea (i.e. see C API strtok for an example of crappy function), and if producing multithread safe code, they are a pain to handle.

#### Avoid name collision

Choose a "namespace" for your functions, and for your defines. This could be:

```
#define GROOVY_LIB_x_MY_CONST_INT 42

void GroovyLib_dosomething() ;
```

#### Beware defines

Defines can't be avoided in C, but they can have side effects!

```
#define MAX(a, b) (a > b) ? (a) : (b)

void doSomething()
{
   int i = 0, j = 1, k ;
   k = MAX(i, j) ;   /* now, k == 1, i == 0 and j == 1 */
   k = MAX(i, j++) ; /* now, k == 2, i == 0 and j == 3, NOT 2, and NOT 1 !!! */
}
```

#### Initialize your variables

Avoid declaring variables without initializing them:

```
int i = 42 ; /* now i = 42 */
int j ;      /* now j can have any value */
double k ;   /* now f can have any value, including invalid ones ! */
```

Uninitialized variables are causes of painful bugs.

#### Know all the C API

The C API function list as described in the K&R is quite small. You'll read the whole list in 20 minutes. You must know those functions.

#### Wanna some experience?

Rewrite the C API. For example, try to write your own version of the string.h functions, to see how it is done.

Comment: I'm wary of any answer that begins with "I have no professionnal experience on C". But the advice is ok. Maybe explain better your perspective and reasoning so it'd be clear to others why they should or shouldn't follow your advice.

Comment: "Inheritance" can be faked somewhat using struct composition. MSVC will handle this without any trouble. GCC may require the -fms-extensions option be used.

Answer (score 8):

You can make a function or object's scope local to its source file by declaring it "static". That helps a bit.

Otherwise, the typical idiom I see for avoiding namespace clashes is to put some kind of facility identifier onto the name. For instance, everything in foo.c might be named foo_*

Answer (score 3):

Good news is that you can program in a semi-object oriented fashion in C.  You can protect data, expose access functions, etc.  It may not have all of the fanciness of C++, but from what I have seen of other people's C++ code, many people do not use the fanciness anyway.  In other words, people write C code inside a class, where in C you'd write the same code without the class container.

First, read a book on C programming and style, K&R is fine.  Second, I'd recommend checking out [CERT Programming Standard](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/CERT+C+Secure+Coding+Standard).  Even though this site is primarily focused on "Secure" coding standards, much of the content here is general code quality standards everyone should follow.  Doing the things mentioned here will improved your quality, eliminate pesky bugs, and as a side effect, make your code more secure.

Comment: Updated link to: [SEI CERT C Coding Standard](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/SEI+CERT+C+Coding+Standard)

Answer (score 1):

You can do object oriented design in pure C.  An easy approach is to think of a module as a `class` with public methods as ordinary functions that require the `this` parameter as an explicit first argument.

It helps if the `class` name is a prefix on the function name, and if all private functions and class data are declared `static`. You build constructors with `malloc()` to get the memory, and explicit initialization of the data fields.

A constructor for an object with entirely private data members can expose an opaque pointer (typed `void *` even, or as a pointer to an incomplete type if type safety is desired). If you want to have only public data members, then a pointer to a publicly defined `struct` works well.

This pattern is followed by a number of libraries. An initialization function returns a cookie that must be passed back to all library methods, and one method serves as a destructor.

Of course, there are other ways to design well in pure C, but if OO works for you, you don't have to abandon it completely.

Comment: Note that the only OO-thing you have with this design is encapsulation. Inheritance and polymorphism will need A LOT MORE of features, but then encapsulation is *always* a good thing, no matter the language.

Comment: @paercebal, true. A fair amount of polymorphism can be done with  function pointers, but you can't have overloading without something doing the name mangling. Inheritance can be modeled in a straightforward way as well. It's worth remembering that C++ was originally implemented as a preprocessor that wrote pure C, after all.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict visibility of file-scope variables and functions to their respective source files (although that doesn't prevent you from passing pointers to these objects around).

For example:

```
/** foo.c */
static void foo_helper() {...} /* foo_helper cannot be called by name 
                                  outside of foo.c */
static int local_state;        /* local state is visible at file scope,
                                  but is not exported to the linker */
```

Answer (score 0):

**C is not C++**

There are some concepts that apply to both, and I think learning how to write clean C will make you a better programmer in C++.

**Think 'data-oriented' instead of 'object oriented'.**

There is a reason C++ kept structs around instead of converting everything to classes. They can DO all the same things but we think of them differently.
I'd say the first thing to do mentally is just accept that a 'class' is just
s struct and class methods are just functions that pass the struct in as the first parameter.

**No, not everything is global. There are three scopes, yea four.**

1. Global should be used the most sparingly, and only struct definitions and HAVE to be global. Header files are used clearly specify the visibility of functions, typedefs and struct definitions.
2. Module (file) scope is often what you should use if you think you need global. Functions and variables can (and should) be defined as static constrained to module (file) scope, unless they are part of an external API, i.e. any function or variable that is global-ish but not referenced by an external header should be static.
3. Function scope is very easy and clean, and passing data into functions is if anything cleaner that the C++ practice of bloating up the object with every little tracking variable.
4. Block scope is the best if your function has grown large. My feeling is that if anything CAN be constrained to block scope, it should be.

In conclusion, C is an elegant weapon from a more civilized age. Simplicity is one of its principle virtues. It has an almost endless list of available libraries, and there are generations of opinions on what makes good C code. That said structures and algorithms you may take for granted as part of the language in more modern languages are often either taken from libraries, or expected to write yourself. I could say some things about privacy and inheritance, but I can't seem to write what I want to say without sounding condescending, so suffice to say that they are not fundamental to computing and can be done without. Privacy can be had in C, if it is really needed, by pre-compiling libraries.

C has been around a long time, and its biggest downside is not a lack of object orientation, but memory safety. It is worth taking the time to understand how things like stack overflows, array overruns, out-of-scope variable exposures happen. There are analogs to all these problems in most languages, but you are more exposed to them in their raw form in C.